# Why does my database query take longer if I select specific columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anybody explain why, when using SQL Azure, the first query below takes four minutes, but the second takes only two seconds?  The only difference is the "orders" prefix in the first line.

#### First query (4 minutes)

```
select top 1 orders.*
from (
    select oi.OrderItemID, o.*
    from OrderItem oi
    inner join [Order] o on oi.OrderID = o.OrderID
    where o.OrderStatusID = 1
) orders
left join GoalProcessingStatus gps on (gps.GoalID = 74 and gps.OrderItemID = 
orders.OrderItemID)
where orders.AccountID = 4
and orders.WhenCreated >= @FromDate
and orders.WhenCreated < @UntilDate
and (gps.GoalProcessingStatusID is null or ( gps.Attempts < 10 and gps.IsProcessed <> 1))
order by orders.WhenCreated
```

#### Second query (two seconds)

```
select top 1 *
from (
    select oi.OrderItemID, o.*
    from OrderItem oi
    inner join [Order] o on oi.OrderID = o.OrderID
    where o.OrderStatusID = 1
) orders
left join GoalProcessingStatus gps on (gps.GoalID = 74 and gps.OrderItemID = 
orders.OrderItemID)
where orders.AccountID = 4
and orders.WhenCreated >= @FromDate
and orders.WhenCreated < @UntilDate
and (gps.GoalProcessingStatusID is null or ( gps.Attempts < 10 and gps.IsProcessed <> 1))
order by orders.WhenCreated
```

### Update

Okay, so it gets weirder. The above still holds, but if I take the slow query and comment out the line *orders.WhenCreated >= @FromDate* line, the time drops down to 2s (FYI WhenCreated is of type datetime and @FromDate is a datetime variable):

#### First query (4 minutes)

```
select top 1 orders.*
from (
    select oi.OrderItemID, o.*
    from OrderItem oi
    inner join [Order] o on oi.OrderID = o.OrderID
    where o.OrderStatusID = 1
) orders
left join GoalProcessingStatus gps on (gps.GoalID = 74 and gps.OrderItemID = 
orders.OrderItemID)
where orders.AccountID = 4
-- REMOVING THE LINE BELOW WILL SPEED UP THE QUERY TO ABOUT 2 SECONDS
-- and orders.WhenCreated >= @FromDate
and orders.WhenCreated < @UntilDate
and (gps.GoalProcessingStatusID is null or ( gps.Attempts < 10 and gps.IsProcessed <> 1))
order by orders.WhenCreated
```

Even stranger, the same performance gain does *not* apply if I comment out the *@UntilDate* comparison below it - it only makes a difference if I remove the @FromDate comparison

## Statistics

Here are the statistics asked for below:

(1 row(s) affected)
Table 'GoalProcessingStatus'. Scan count 12486, logical reads 811590, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'OrderItem'. Scan count 9206, logical reads 29452, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Order'. Scan count 1, logical reads 48756, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row(s) affected)

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 796 ms,  elapsed time = 430468 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

(1 row(s) affected)
Table 'GoalProcessingStatus'. Scan count 0, logical reads 75714, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'OrderItem'. Scan count 9207, logical reads 29455, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Order'. Scan count 1, logical reads 48759, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row(s) affected)

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 1024 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

Looks like there is a scan on GoalProcessingStatus, although I couldn't guess why it is being activated only in the former scenario.

[image: Here is a link to the execution plan]

## Indexes

I've been asked for the two main indexes in question:

`CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [nci_wi_GoalProcessingStatus_1DE49F3EF3D056EFB506085E35F68FFE] ON [dbo].[GoalProcessingStatus]
    (
        [GoalID] ASC
    )
    INCLUDE (   [Attempts],
        [IsProcessed],
        [OrderItemID]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO`

The second index (used in the faster query) is simply the primary key for GoalProcessingStatus table.

Of interest, I did not create the first query.  It was automatically done by Azure's indexing service.  It's actually a valid and useful index, but obviously not relevant for this query.  Interesting then that SQL chose to use it.

Comment: first and foremost select * is not a good idea... try to trim it down and then use index

Comment: WhenCreated is of what data type?, @FromDate is of what data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for posting the STATISTICS IO and Execution Plan. Please post the various indexes and schema associated with these tables.

### Why your query times vary

In SELECTing just the orders.* data, the SQL Server Query Optimizer is deciding to use "GoalProcessingStatus.nci_wi_Goal..." index. This index encompasses every GoalProcessingStatus column you reference in the predicate.

In SELECTing the * data, the SQL Server Query Optimizer is deciding to use "IX_U_GoalP..." index and doing subsequent lookups on the Clustered index. This is because it needs all the columns from the GoalProcessingStatus table.

## Moving Forward

To move forward with solving this problem, you'll need to figure out why performance on index "GoalProcessingStatus.nci_wi_Goal..." is so poor. It's difficult for me to help without the indexes and schema definitions. Also, the XML Execution plan would also provide more information.

## Updated

After revisiting your query "order.*" query, the only columns being referenced in the predicate are GoalProcessingStatusID, Attempts, and IsProcessed. your non-clustered index may lack uniqueness.

Comment: "Can anybody explain why, when using SQL Azure, the first query below takes four minutes, but the second takes only two seconds?" 

I did provide an  answer to the question. It is stated in "Why your query times vary".

Answer (score 0):

Curious, could you not move the where logic for Orders up to the first portion to limit the size of initial recordset?

Two things that may be happening

1:  Bad Query plan.  If you hard code the values you are using in the parameters @FromDate and @untildate, do you get the same result?  If it runs quickly chances are you've got a bad query plan due to parameter sniffing.

2: (Unlikely)  I see from your QPs that you are using 2 different indexes for GoalProcessingStatus (one in the fast plan and one in the slow one).  If you look at the index definitions for IX_U_Goal... and nci_wi_goal... it may give you some insight on how it's taking longer for one vs the other.

I do believe if you move the orders logic in the where clause into your first sub query it should be much quicker in both cases.

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks for the reply.  The SQL you see was formatted by myself for this SO question, but in fact was originally generated by EntityFramework.  It is certainly not quite what I would write myself.  FYI I have simply replaced the EF query with a stored procedure containing the logic above and this at least allows my application to run smoothly.  I'm still interested though in why the plan would choose such a grossly different route.